# When using VBA to assign a fixed list of items to a data validation dropdown, the list becomes un-editable and Excel thinks there is an error

Tags: excel, vba, validation, user-defined-functions

I have a worksheet template I use for all my hand calculations at work (I'm an engineer). I often refer to certain material properties, so I wrote some user-defined functions in VBA that reference a fixed material properties list in the code to speed up my workflow. I have one function called 'LISTMATERIALS()' where I can enter a cell reference and it will add a data validation list with all the materials in my little database, and then another function 'MATERIALPROPERTY()' that can look up the yield stress or whatever property of the material I am considering. When I call the LISTMATERIALS function, it sets up the data validation no problem. But after I've saved and closed the file, Excel thinks there is an error and will ask me to recover the file the next time I open it. It always deletes this data validation and everything else is fine. I can't figure out why it has a problem, here are my functions:

```
Function MATERIALPROPERTY(Material, Property)
    Set SYDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set STDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set EMDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set DDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set PDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set NDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Material = CStr(Material)
    Dim matNames(33)
    Dim matArray(33)
    'Add materials here: Name, Yeild, Tensile, Youngs, Density, Poisson, Note
    matArray(0) = ("A36, 36000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(1) = ("A500A, 33000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(2) = ("A500B, 42000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(3) = ("A500C, 45000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(4) = ("A514, 100000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(5) = ("A516-70, 37000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(6) = ("A572-42, 42000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(7) = ("A572-50, 50000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(8) = ("A572-55, 55000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(9) = ("A572-60, 60000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(10) = ("A572-65, 65000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(11) = ("A992, 50000, 65000, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(12) = ("4140HT, 60000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(13) = ("4140QT 1200F, 84100, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(14) = ("4140QT 700F, 212000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(15) = ("4340N, 103000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(16) = ("4340QT 1200F, 106000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(17) = ("4340QT 1100F, 114000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(18) = ("4340QT 1000F, 145000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(19) = ("4340QT 800F, 213900, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(20) = ("8630N, 79800, 89900, 27100000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(21) = ("13-8 H950, 205000, 1, 28300000, 0.282, 0.300, None")
    matArray(22) = ("13-8 H1000, 190000, 1, 28300000, 0.282, 0.300, None")
    matArray(23) = ("13-8 H1025, 175000, 1, 28300000, 0.282, 0.300, None")
    matArray(24) = ("13-8 H1050, 165000, 1, 28300000, 0.282, 0.300, None")
    matArray(25) = ("13-8 H1100, 135000, 1, 28300000, 0.282, 0.300, None")
    matArray(26) = ("13-8 H1150, 90000, 1, 28300000, 0.282, 0.300, None")
    matArray(27) = ("GRADE8, 130000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(28) = ("E60xx, 60000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(29) = ("E70xx, 70000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(30) = ("E80xx, 80000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(31) = ("E90xx, 90000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(32) = ("E100xx, 100000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")
    matArray(33) = ("E120xx, 120000, 1, 29000000, 0.284, 0.300, None")

    iterationNumber = 0
    For Each materialSpec In matArray
        If Len(materialSpec) > 0 Then
            materialItems = Split(materialSpec, ", ")
            matName = materialItems(0)
            matYeild = CDec(materialItems(1))
            matTensile = CDec(materialItems(2))
            matYoungs = CDec(materialItems(3))
            matDensity = CDec(materialItems(4))
            matPoisson = CDec(materialItems(5))
            matNote = materialItems(6)
            
            matNames(iterationNumber) = matName
            iterationNumber = iterationNumber + 1
            
            With SYDict
                .Add matName, matYeild
            End With
            With STDict
                .Add matName, matTensile
            End With
            With EMDict
                .Add matName, matYoungs
            End With
            With DDict
                .Add matName, matDensity
            End With
            With PDict
                .Add matName, matPoisson
            End With
            With NDict
                .Add matName, matNote
            End With
        End If
        
    Next materialSpec
    
    If Property = "ALL" Then
        MATERIALPROPERTY = Join(matNames, ",")
    ElseIf Property = "SY" Then
        If SYDict.Exists(Material) Then
            MATERIALPROPERTY = SYDict(Material)
        Else
            MATERIALPROPERTY = "Unknown Material"
        End If
    ElseIf Property = "ST" Then
        If STDict.Exists(Material) Then
            MATERIALPROPERTY = STDict(Material)
        Else
            MATERIALPROPERTY = "Unknown Material"
        End If
    ElseIf Property = "EM" Then
        If EMDict.Exists(Material) Then
            MATERIALPROPERTY = EMDict(Material)
        Else
            MATERIALPROPERTY = "Unknown Material"
        End If
    ElseIf Property = "D" Then
        If DDict.Exists(Material) Then
            MATERIALPROPERTY = DDict(Material)
        Else
            MATERIALPROPERTY = "Unknown Material"
        End If
     ElseIf Property = "P" Then
        If PDict.Exists(Material) Then
            MATERIALPROPERTY = PDict(Material)
        Else
            MATERIALPROPERTY = "Unknown Material"
        End If
     ElseIf Property = "N" Then
        If NDict.Exists(Material) Then
            MATERIALPROPERTY = NDict(Material)
        Else
            MATERIALPROPERTY = "Unknown Material"
        End If
    Else
        MATERIALPROPERTY = "Specify 'SY', 'ST', 'EM', 'D', 'P', or 'N'"
    End If

End Function

Function LISTMATERIALS(cellReference)
    matList = Module1.MATERIALPROPERTY("ALL", "ALL")
    Range(cellReference).Validation.Delete
    Range(cellReference).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=matList
    LISTMATERIALS = "Assigned Material List to Cell " & cellReference
End Function
```

The only other weird behavior I have seen is that once the data validation has been set up, it seems to be totally locked down so that I can't manually edit it from the data validation window in Excel, which I haven't seen before. Anybody see anything wrong with how I've set this up?

Comment: Make sure whatever you're assigning to `Formula1` is no longer than 255 characters.

Comment: ...looks like it's 284, so too long.

Comment: Ugh so simple, so annoying lol. Thanks Tim!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has 1048579 rows and 16384 columns! It is so simple that any list you create on the fly can be stored in a row or a column. Then the address of the area containing the values of the list will be given to the parameter of .Validation.Add.... To do this I use a helper Function which takes the list (of any size) and converts it into a one-dimensional array, then copies it to the sheet starting from the cell we define with horizontal or vertical orientation depending on our desire and returns us the address of the area  where the list was copied:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tester()
   Debug.Print LISTMATERIALS(Me.Range("J1"))
End Sub

Function LISTMATERIALS(validCell As Range) As String
   Dim matList As String, r As Range

   'in next line call a helper function to create a list with 70 items
   matList = listMakerSimulator(70)
   'copy the list in I1,I2...I70 and get the returned range
   Set r = arr1D_ToRange(matList, Me.Range("I1"), xco_vertically)
   validCell.Validation.Delete
   validCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=" & r.Address
   LISTMATERIALS = "Assigned Material List to Cell " & validCell.Address
End Function

'helper function to create list for this example
Function listMakerSimulator(cnt As Long) As String
   Dim c As Long
   listMakerSimulator = "aaaa 1"
   For c = 2 To cnt
      listMakerSimulator = listMakerSimulator & ",aaaa " & c
   Next
End Function
```

**PUT THE NEXT CODE IN A LIBRARY MODULE (not sheet module)**

```
Option Explicit

'--------------------------------------------------
' helper Enum for easy setting and understanding
' the parameter orient at Function arr1D_ToRange 
'--------------------------------------------------
Public Enum COPY_ORIENTATION
   xco_horizontally = 1  'the default behavior
   xco_vertically = 2
End Enum

'---------------------------------------------------------------------
' function for your library. 
' listOfStrings As String> string with comma separated values
' startCopyAt As Range> range of one cell to start the copy of the list values
' orient As COPY_ORIENTATION> how copy (whitch orientation) the list
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function arr1D_ToRange(listOfStrings As String, startCopyAt As Range, Optional orient As COPY_ORIENTATION = xco_horizontally) As Range
   Dim v As Variant, rng As Range, itms As Long
   If listOfStrings = vbNullString Then Exit Function
   'the startCopyAt have to be range of ONE cell
   If startCopyAt.CountLarge > 1 Then Set startCopyAt = startCopyAt.Cells(1)
   v = Split(listOfStrings, ",")
   itms = UBound(v) - LBound(v) + 1
   With Application.WorksheetFunction
      If orient = xco_vertically Then
         'copy to range vertically (Column)
         Set rng = startCopyAt.Resize(itms)
         rng = .Transpose(v)
      Else
         'copy to range horizontally (Row)
         Set rng = startCopyAt.Resize(1, itms)
         rng = .Transpose(.Transpose(v))
      End If
   End With
   Set arr1D_ToRange = rng
End Function
```

[image]